# Help with JSforce query - 'Bind variables only allowed in Apex code'

Tags: soql, jsforce

I'm trying to execute the following query using [JSforce](https://jsforce.github.io/):

```
conn.query('SELECT RecordId FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId=:' + userId + 'AND HasReadAccess = true AND RecordId IN :' + listOfIds + ' LIMIT 200', function (err, res) {}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Bind variables only allowed in Apex code

So I googled it, and found [this](https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce/issues/551) post, which suggests to do something like this:

```
var parentObjIdArray = [ '', '', '', ... ];
conn.sobject('Child_Obj__c').find({
  ParentObj__c : parentObjIdArray
}, [ 'Id', 'field_1__c', 'field_2__c' ]).then(function(records) {
   // ...
});
```

I modified my query and this what I have so far:

```
var userIds = ['0061t000004bgfcAAA','0061t00000KLjjkAAD'];
conn.sobject('UserRecordAccess').find({UserId: userIds}, ['Id']).then(function(records) {
    console.log(records);
});
```

But when I run it in the JSforce console, nothing happens, it's stuck.

Also, as you can see on my SOQL query on the top, I use **two** binding variables, how can it be achieved?

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error indicates your SOQL is incorrect. You need to use normal syntax, which includes proper quotes, parentheses, etc:

```
conn.query(
    "SELECT RecordId FROM UserRecordAccess " +
    "WHERE UserId = '" + userId + "' " + 
      "AND HasReadAccess = true "+
      "AND RecordId IN ('" + listOfIds.join("','") + "') " +
    "LIMIT 200", function (err, res) {});
```

As for the second syntax, should you choose to use find, you'd do:

```
conn
  .sobject("UserRecordAccess")
  .find({
    UserId: { $eq: userId },
    RecordId: { $in: listOfIds }
  },
  fields)
  .then(function(records) {
  // do stuff here
  });
```